# Spotify Mac: Is there way to "Like" currently playing song using a shortcut?

Tags: shortcut, spotify

I don't want to open spotify app every time to like the song i'm listening. I'd like to just press a global shortcut button to like current song while working in another app.

Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented a working solution, which is more like a hack.

You need to script the Spotify application simulating mouse clicks, which supposes it is always in a similar state (in my case full screen on a different space) and you will lose control of your Mac for a few seconds.

I wanted to do it in full Applescript but it does not seem to be possible as Spotify is only partly scriptable, API needs a refreshing token every hour, and AS mouse commands are failing. I needed to call python and load an additional module.

Then use a third party which allows me to assign a keystroke to the AppleScript.

Lot of trouble for such a simple command.